# MySQL | date型の比較方法

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

htmlのフォーム送信より、type="date"の値を、SQL内のdate型カラムと比較しようとしますが、抽出できません。
ソースコードは以下になります。
なにかSQL,PHP,htmlのformの記述で間違っていますか？

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
  <input type="date" name="search_date">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

//event_dateカラムはdate型です
$search_date = $_POST["search_date"];
$sql = "select * from sample where event_date = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
//DBハンドラー用意済み
$stmt->execute($stmt, $search_date);
```

ちなみに、date型カラムの抽出条件として、type="date"のvalueで対応できますか？

Comment: 今回の問題とは関係ないと思われますが、htmlspecialcharsの使い道を間違えています。あとで、何のための関数か見直してみてください。

Answer (score 3):

フォームから送信される値はISO 8601形式ですので

```
2015-08-01T02:03:04+09:00
```

のように日付と時刻を`T`で区切り、末尾にタイムゾーン指定が付加されています。

一方MySQLが認識可能な形式は

- 15-08-01
- 2015-08-01
- 2015-08-01 02:03:04

という3形式の記号違いと記号なし版の都合6種類です。なので質問中のSQLは日付とは認識されず、`event_date`をISO 8601以外の文字列に変換してからパラメーターと比較していると思われます。

日付と認識させるためにはPHP側で`date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["search_date"]))`のように変換をかけてやればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ご指摘頂いた内容で出来ました！