# fullpage.js | Chrome不具合

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Chromeで、fullpage.js（http://kana-lier.com/javascript/fullpage-js/#sec2_1）を実装しましたが、一度のスクロールで、ふたページ飛んだり、何度もスクロールしたりと動作が不安定です。

safariでは正常動作します。

Chrome特有のバグの様子で、何か解決策はありますか？ 
consoleでも特にエラーはありません。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/13835 とマルチポストでしょうか？ほかにも http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12861/ も https://teratail.com/questions/13746 と同一ですね。そのことについてなんの記載もありませんが、[マルチポストについての理解](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1766/)は大丈夫でしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

そのような明らかにバグだと思われる不具合については、[GithubのIssuesを漁る](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?q=chrome%20is%3Aopen)と解決策が見つかる可能性が一番高いと思います。実際に、[Chrome44.0から不具合が起きていることが報告されています](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1389)。どうやらChromeが原因のバグのようで、私も再現を確認しました。

一時的な回避策としてプラグインオプション[`css3:false`を指定することが作者から提案されています](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1389#issuecomment-124147999)が、根本的な解決はChromeのバグフィックスを待つしかないようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます、CSSをfalseにして正常動作しました。助かりました！